# how to add scroll bar in android on justified textview

Tags: android, scrollbar, textview

I am adding scrollbar on text view like below but last few lines of text get cropped and not visible. Why this happening and how to solve this?

Xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:orientation="vertical" 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
           android:background="@drawable/back">

    <com.abc.xyz.TextViewEx
        android:id="@+id/etext1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/betxt"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_margin" 
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_margin"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity-

```
textView1 = (TextViewEx) findViewById (R.id.etext1);
textView1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things you could try to fix this problem:

1)Try adding the `android:maxLines`. 
Then add `TextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())` in your java code.

2) You could put android:singleLine="true" in the layout of the textview so it does not become bigger than its container.

3) Try putting android:gravity="bottom|left" in the textview's layout and see if that will align the textview to the bottom left.

I suggest to go with 1st solution since you are using `android:scrollbars="vertical"`,i t may work for you.

Comment: @JohnR so wat problem you face in that case.It would help me to provide solution over it.

Comment: Did you added the android:maxLines to textview.

Comment: can you try adding it,once.Because,i feel scrollbar would work more nicely with maxLines.I hope you wont mind trying that once.

Comment: ok i will. but I have different dimensions for different device so text size on some devices bigger than other so how many lines I have to set?

Comment: try on one device and put 5-10 lines and just check if your problem is solved.if the problem still remains den we wuld be needing some other way out.